# FTP on File Explorer gives "Details 200 Type set to A 227 Entering passive mode"

Tags: ftp

I am trying to connect to my FTP server via File Explorer. I am sure I configured my settings and passive mode correctly, but I still get this error message:

[image]

I am not sure why this happens so I am asking for some advice

> Edit: I was able to connect using command prompt and download, upload, and delete files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my NAT Router field was set to the ip address of my router page, all I had to do was change it to the public ip of my website and it works :)

Answer (score 2):

See picture:

[image: Use the following IP]

I guess this is the problem that the file manager does not automatically convert to an external IP. So if you want to solve this problem, set it directly to the external IP directly on the FTP server.If you use the filezilla server, you can direct setting this blank(your external ip. If you don't know public ip, you can use this URL http://www.whatismyip.com.tw/ to get external ip)

Comment: Yes, this is essentially what the problem was. +1 to help you get started :)